# first line of caption in minipage / subfigure not at same height although `[b]` argument is used

Tags: vertical-alignment, captions, subcaption

I modified the code [of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68448118/how-to-have-separate-captions-in-the-same-level-in-the-minipage-environment-with) as follows:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h!]
\noindent\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
    \begin{align*}
    &F_1(a, b) \leftarrow a \le 0 \\ 
    &F_2(a, b) \leftarrow  F_1(a, b) \\ 
    \end{align*}
\caption{bla bla bla bla, bla bla bla bla, bla bla bla bla, bla bla bla bla, bla bla bla bla}
\end{subfigure}%
\noindent\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
\begin{lstlisting}[]
   while(a < 0){
   a++;
}
\end{lstlisting}
\caption{bla bla bla bla, blsdf asdf asdf asdfasdfasdf asdfa bla bla bla, bla bla bla bla, bla bla bla bla, bla bla bla bla, blablabasdf asdf asdf asdf }
\end{subfigure}%
\caption{text}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Although I used the argument `[b]`, the captions' first lines of the 2 subfigures are not as the same height and they overlap each other. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

**EDIT**
Thanks to leandriis comment, I could solve the overlapping problem

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h!]
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
    \begin{align*}
    &F_1(a, b) \leftarrow a \le 0 \\ 
    &F_2(a, b) \leftarrow  F_1(a, b) \\ 
    \end{align*}
\caption{bla bla bla bla, bla bla bla bla, bla bla bla bla, bla bla bla bla, bla bla bla bla}
\end{subfigure}%
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
\begin{lstlisting}[]
   while(a < 0){
   a++;
}
\end{lstlisting}
\caption{bla bla bla bla, blsdf asdf asdf asdfasdfasdf asdfa bla bla bla, bla bla bla bla, bla bla bla bla, bla bla bla bla, blablabasdf asdf asdf asdf }
\end{subfigure}%
\caption{text}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Regarding the overlap: You may want to remove the first `\noindent` and replace the second one with `\hfill`. Regarding the vertical alignment: Both captions' last lines are at the same vertical position.

Comment: @leandriis many thanks for your very helpful comment. What I actually want to do is to align both captions' FIRST lines at the same vertical position. Is there a way of doing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store the content of the listing in a box *first* and then use that box as part of the `subfigure`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\newsavebox{\codebox}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\linewidth}
    \begin{align*}
      &F_1(a, b) \leftarrow a \leq 0   \\ 
      &F_2(a, b) \leftarrow  F_1(a, b)
    \end{align*}
    \caption{bla bla bla bla, bla bla bla bla, bla bla bla bla, bla bla bla bla, bla bla bla bla}
  \end{subfigure}
  \hfill
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\linewidth}
    \begin{lstlisting}[basicstyle=\ttfamily]
while(a < 0) {
 a++;
}
    \end{lstlisting}
    \caption{bla bla bla bla, blsdf asdf asdf asdfasdfasdf asdfa bla bla bla, bla bla bla bla, bla bla bla bla, bla bla bla bla, blablabasdf asdf asdf asdf}
  \end{subfigure}
  \caption{Without storing \texttt{lstlisting} in a box \emph{first}.}

  \bigskip
  
  \subcaptionbox{bla bla bla bla, bla bla bla bla, bla bla bla bla, bla bla bla bla, bla bla bla bla}[0.45\linewidth][b]{%
    \begin{align*}
      &F_1(a, b) \leftarrow a \leq 0   \\ 
      &F_2(a, b) \leftarrow  F_1(a, b)
    \end{align*}
  }%
  \hfill
  % Store listing inside \codebox
  \begin{lrbox}{\codebox}
    \begin{lstlisting}[basicstyle=\ttfamily]
while(a < 0){
 a++;
}
    \end{lstlisting}
\end{lrbox}%
  \subcaptionbox{bla bla bla bla, blsdf asdf asdf asdfasdfasdf asdfa bla bla bla, bla bla bla bla, bla bla bla bla, bla bla bla bla, blablabasdf asdf asdf asdf}[0.45\linewidth][b]{%
    \usebox{\codebox}%
  }%
  \caption{Storing \texttt{lstlisting} in a box \emph{first}.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: many thanks @Werner for your answer. Is it then possible to add a `\label` to the 2 subcaptions of the subcaptionbox?

Comment: @ecjb: Yes. Insert it as part of the first argument that contains the caption. You can also revert back to the `subfigure` environment; it works the same. `\subcaptionbox` is just the base definition provided by [`subcaption`](//ctan.org/pkg/subcaption).